# Include TinyMCE in Joomla Frontend

Tags: joomla, tinymce, frontend

I tried to include TinyMCE into my template but if I try to edit the texts in the frontend I have only a html-tag view. Have anybody got some hints for me?

That's the website and the template, perhaps this could help a little bit:

http://www.sonnen-center-hermeskeil.de

Comment: and how exactly did you try and include the TinyMCE Editor in your template? Also, why would you embed it in your template and not a custom module?

Comment: I'm a total newbie in writing templates but I want to edit my content with TinyMCE. I have found something like '<?php mosShowHead(); ?>
<?php if ( $my->id ) {initEditor(); } ?>' in the head area... but your hint sounds great.. can you explain me how i can use tinyMCE in my frontend ? The Editor chosen for the user is tinyMCE.

Comment: by "content", I assume you mean the article. This is done via the Article Manager via the Joomla backend

Comment: Yes, I know about this method in the backend, but i've got users which aren't that much into computer stuff and so on and i don't want them to get in the backend, the should get the possibility to edit their articles in the frontend in an editor :D That's my problem :/

Comment: If you are logged in and have the right to edit an article an edit icon will automatically be displayed.

Comment: Yes, but only in html-mode not with an editor, even i've chosen one in the backend and that is why I try to include it into my template.

Answer (score 1):

If anything of the above didn't help, chances are that the access to the plugin is restricted. Go to `Plugin-Manager -> Editor - TinyMCE` and check that `Access` is set accordingly. If e.g. a common user is allowed to edit the article but the Access Rule for TinyMCE is set to "Special", Joomla will display the mere HTML Editor **even if there is no other Editor available or enabled**. The same goes for setting Access to "Registered" when a public user is allowed to edit an article.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but the Access settings are Public :( Still not working at all

Answer (score 0):

Go to Plugins and disable all editors there except to tinyMCE. Then once again make sure you have selected as a default editor tinyMCE. You can also define the default editor for each user from "User Manager", by opening the user and defining his/her default editor.

Comment: That's a very strange behavior. Which editors are enabled in your plugins?

Comment: Only tinyMCE, could it be that this behavior is caused by my the template written by myself ?

Comment: It's possible that your custom template misses some essential includes. What version of Joomla are you using? Also, can you post the code of your template's index.php?

Comment: I'm using Joomla Version 2.5. It could be possible that some essential includes are missing and that was my basic problem from the beginning, i think ;)

Comment: That's my head 
`<?php defined('_JEXEC') or die; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" dir="<?php echo $this->direction; ?>">
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/template.css"/>
 </head>
`

Comment: And this is the part of my body where the articles are shown 
`  <div id="mitte">
   <div id="beitrage">
     <jdoc:include type="component" />
     
   </div>
  </div>`

Comment: You're missing the default "head" include. Put the following in your index.php, just after the     <head> is opened:
    <jdoc:include type="head" />
Let me know if this solved your issue.

Comment: Your index.php should have the following format:
    <?php defined('_JEXEC') or die;
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" >
<head>
<jdoc:include type="head" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/template.css"/> 
</head>

Comment: Sorry but without access to your Joomla installation there's nothing else I can think of. The TinyMCE editor should show if you have disabled all other editors.